# Get all the text under a element

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-xml

My xml looks like this

```
<Element> text <B>text<B></Element>
```

Unknown number of B tags or tags even of a different name.

How do i get the text from these?  so it would be like this

text text

using linq to xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following assuming `XElement` was pointing to the Element tag

```
var root = GetRoot();
var text = root.Elements("B").Select(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: To include tags with a different name, you'd call `root.Elements()` without a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

As you need any children not just the "B"s
if root is your Element tag as as XElement

```
var text = string.Empty;
root.DescendentsAndSelf().Select(x => text += x.Value);
```